# Openxava UI development

Tags: openxava

Can anyone explain how to write our own JSP page and use entity to show it on that page. I mean i do not want to use the supplied jsp files. I wanna develop my own JSP pages and use the entity to that page.(like in customer registration form). please provide me steps to make it possible.

any help is highly appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

That topic is explained in OpenXava reference guide:
http://openxava.wikispaces.com/customizing_en